# What's the best practice for renaming a table and adding attributes to the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From a best practice point of view which is better:

- Create a migration that changes the name of a table and adds attributes to that table in a single migration.

OR

- Create a migration for the table change and another one for the change of attributes.

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Minimal downtime? Fault tolerance? Readability of the migration? What is the reason for the table name change? What is the reason for the new attributes? Is the reason the same?

Comment: There's a bit of complexity to this, potentially. Is this a live production system or development? Do you have pk/fk relationships? These, plus the questions @spickermann asked will dictate the best practice. You can find lots of information on other considerations when running migrations online. https://blog.codeship.com/rails-migrations-zero-downtime/

Comment: I'm going for cleanest on the optimization front, and this is for development. The reason for the table change is to make better use of the table. Right now it's not being used at all, but it is being referenced in some places, so its not like I can simply delete the old table and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a new migration

```
$ bin/rails generate migration RenameOldTable_to_NewTable
```

Step 2: Inside the migration file, add this code.

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
  end
end
```

Step 3: Run the migration

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This is a very simple way to rename a table using migration. All the attributes will remain same as old table.